# Как правильно подключить CSS в webpack?

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, npm

Всем привет.Никак **не могу подключить CSS файл к webpack.** Пишет ошибку в строке 10 но так как с `node.js` и `npm` незнаком очень трудно для меня разобратся.

Уже установил **style-loader**.

`style.css` находится в одном директории с `home.js`  [ошибка который я получаю](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycamd.jpg)

Вот мой **webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./home",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
      ]
    }

}
```

Также **home.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import css from './style.css';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очепятка у вас, после блока `output` забыли запятую. Забирай:

```
"use strict";

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./home",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое и дай бог здоровье :) @Klimenkomud

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Всегда пожалуйста :)